# How to correctly manage state while passing complex initial data as props to child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

**[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-wood-rbvcyy?file=/src/components/NestedForm.vue) is the whole example that demonstrates the problem.**

I stumbled across this issue, which is not strictly a Vue issue, but rather a consequence of JavaScript itself and pass by reference. **Long story short, my object inside child component, passed as prop is the same as object in parent component and I can mutate it directly from child.**

Imagine this parent component:

```
import NestedForm from "./components/NestedForm.vue";
import { reactive } from "vue";

const formData = reactive({
  name: "Some name",
  ids: [{ number: "ES589348", type: "passport" }],
});
```

It's a form component, to edit some entity that has a name and an array of ID documents. To make things nice and dandy I have a child component to edit IDs part of the form:

```
<NestedForm v-model="formData.ids" />
```

Now inside NestedForm I have this code:

```
const props = defineProps(["modelValue"]);
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

const ids = reactive([...props.modelValue]);

const addId = () => ids.push({ number: "", type: "" });
const save = () => emit("update:modelValue", ids);
```

The problem is objects are being passed by reference. So even tho I destruct the array, which creates a new one, my objects inside the array has the same reference as in parent component (`ids[0] === formData.ids[0]`). As a consequence when I change any object in child component it is reflected in parent component **without emitting the event**. Which is basically mutating a prop directly and Vue advises to communicate via events with parent component.

Funny things happen also when you emit the event with ids object, which is a reactive Proxy. Now suddenly parent component holds the same reference as child component (so parent `formData.ids === ids` from child component) and when you keep adding ID objects it is now also immediately reflected in parent component.

**The one solution that I found** is doing a deep clone of my input props and deep cloning my output data while emitting the event. This way what happens inside child component, stays in child component until I emit the event. However this seems very weird that I have to do this.

I either have an architectural/design problem or I'm missing something else. Could you please tell me what am I missing here?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-wood-rbvcyy?file=/src/components/NestedForm.vue) is the whole example to play around with. Try changing the first entry, you will see it is immediately visible in parent component and it shouldn't. I want to happen only upon event (as it should be, according to Vue docs, components should communicate via events). Try adding some new IDs. Nothing happens — yet. Click save button. Add some more IDs and you will notice, now it's also binded with parent.

Comment: For me it's the logical consequence of vue.
A property is always bind reactive, and if you change something on the child this will change in the parent, because you don't have two property, but one reactive.

If you don't want this, you need in your child to declare a new value and assign the property, but it can still stay bind! In this case you have to do a ```this.formDataChild = JSON.stringigy(JSON.parse(formData))```

Comment: Yeah.. I mean I get this is the same reference. But it feels weird to do all this deep copies of objects to conform to event communication and get rid of the same object reference problem. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong on the design level or I just have to live with this. For primitives it's super simple, things get hard when you introduce complex data structures.

Comment: Yes it's weird, but vue works like this.
It's create some misunderstood and somethime a lot of "WTF happened", because the reactive stay bind and change is done in a higher level. But it's common, and to debind a property you have to clone (with json stringify/parse).

If you use vueX and try to change a store data without mutation, you will see a message from vue, because, yes you can change directly a store data in a component, because of the binding effect (but vue doesn't like that).

Comment: If you place an object into multiple arrays and then you modify it, you should expect it to change in every array. If you want a copy of it into one of the arrays you have to destructure it (`const objCopy = { ...obj }`). Now changing `objCopy` won't affect `obj` (unless the modified prop is an object itself, of course). It's how JavaScript was designed.

Comment: For me, it's not weird. It's how we deal with JS. If you want to make it a little "nicer". You can move your props to vuex/pinia. Now you officially access the same object

Answer (score 0):

So that is why Vue uses the Store.(Pinia, Vuex)
You get one place with the value and one place to mutate that value, all other components use these actions to mutate the state.
And since in every component you want the value you get it from a computed property whenever is a change in the store ALL COMPONENTS GET THE UPDATED VALUE AUTOMATICALLY

In your case there should be a store like

```
const state = { ids: ['same value']}
const mutations = { updateIds(){...}}
const actions = { updateStateOfIds(){...} }
```

and then in any component you have something like

computed:{...mapState({ ids : state => state.ids})

<button @click"update">

function update(payload){ store.dispatch('updateStateOfIds', payload }